# MySQL: Select one row from left join only once in result wth multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

Alright, with help from SO and some of my own admittedly limited brain power, I got my query mostly working. I'm getting the result I want from the `LEFT JOIN` and it's showing up in the outer query. However, it shows up multiple times for each row with the same ID, which is expected, but that's not what I need...

**I am wondering if it's possible to only show the joined result once.** I found lots of answers online for only pulling the first row from a table that was left joined. However, what I'm looking for is to only show the joined result once *in the result* (doesn't have to be the first time).

This is [a simplified version of] my query:

```
select
    `order`.order_id,
    `order`.total,
    `order`.comment,
    `order`.shipping_cost,
    `ct`.amount as credit
from `order`
left join (
    select
        customer_id,
        sum(amount) as amount
    from `customer_transaction`
    where
        amount > 0
        and integrated = 0
    group by
        customer_id
) as ct
    on `ct`.`customer_id` = `order`.`customer_id`
where
    `order`.integrated = 0;
```

What this is supposed to do is get not-yet-integrated order information while including customer credit. Unfortunately the credit is stored as rows in the `ct` table, not associated with a specific order, which sort of makes sense, but the software that is integrating this wants this number on an order.

The above query "works", until one customer has more than one order. In this case, if I use the above query, it will effectively think all orders had credit applied. For example, the above query returns a result like:

```
+-------------+----------+-----------+---------+---------------+--------+
| customer_id | order_id | total     | comment | shipping_cost | credit |
+-------------+----------+-----------+---------+---------------+--------+
|       52227 |   184589 |   28.6910 |         |       12.7410 | 8.0000 |
|       52227 |   184590 |   28.6910 |         |       12.7410 | 8.0000 |
+-------------+----------+-----------+---------+---------------+--------+
```

This customer has $8 in credit "on their account", not $16. I.e., the sum of non-used credit transactions on the customer adds up to 8. I am trying to get that credit to only show up once. In other words, this is the result I would like:

```
+-------------+----------+-----------+---------+---------------+--------+
| customer_id | order_id | total     | comment | shipping_cost | credit |
+-------------+----------+-----------+---------+---------------+--------+
|       52227 |   184589 |   28.6910 |         |       12.7410 | 8.0000 |
|       52227 |   184590 |   28.6910 |         |       12.7410 | NULL   |
+-------------+----------+-----------+---------+---------------+--------+
```

(Note the NULL in the bottom right corner. It could also be 0, or maybe even 8/$NUM_ROWS. I'd have to check if the software would work with that. Probably not.)

The reason for this craziness is because one piece of software stores the credit as one or more rows associated with the customer, and the other expects it as part of one order, and it's supposed to all integrate "at once". It runs one query to get all order info, including credit, and a second for line-items (no credit). So...I need to bring the credit in with the order, then set it to integrated=1 so it won't be used the next time around (I already have this part working).

Any ideas how I can only display the credit once, or is this not doable with a "simple" query (as opposed to code)?

Thanks

Comment: Create [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with your test data and post the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using a left join.  The idea is to have a sequence number in the first table of the `left join`:

```
select o.order_id, o.total, o.comment, o.shipping_cost, ct.amount as credit
from (select o.*,
             @rn :=  if(@cid = customer_id, @rn + 1, 1) as rn,
             @cid := customer_id
      from `order` o cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @cid := 0) vars
     ) o left join
     (select customer_id, sum(amount) as amount
      from `customer_transaction`
      where amount > 0 and integrated = 0
      group by customer_id
     ) ct
     on `ct`.`customer_id` = o.`customer_id` and o.rn = 1
where o.integrated = 0;
```

A `left join` keeps all rows in the first table and matching rows in the second table, if necessary.  Because the condition `o.rn = 1` only matches the first row, then only the first row will get the values.